# コードにエラー等出ず、プレビュー画面も表示されますが、BGMが再生されません。

Tags: swift, ios, swift3

音楽ファイル名は"chino.mp3"です。音楽を取り込み、アプリを開いた時点でBGMが鳴るようにしたつもりで、エラー等起きず、ビルド画面が表示されますが、音楽が再生されません。修正点等ありましたら、ご指摘お願いいたします。

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var audioPlayerInstance : AVAudioPlayer! = nil

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let soundFilePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "chino", ofType: "mp3")!
    let sound:URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: soundFilePath)
    do {
        audioPlayerInstance = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: sound, fileTypeHint: nil)
    } catch {
        print("失敗")
    }
    audioPlayerInstance.prepareToPlay()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Comment: `audioPlayerInstance.play()`がコード中に見当たりませんが? `Bundle.url(forResource:withExtension:)`を使えば1行不要になるのにとか、「なんで`fileTypeHint`を指定しないのに`init(contentsOf:fileTypeHint:)`を使うんだろう?」とか、直したいところはありますが、`play()`を呼べば再生が始まるはずです。(ちなみに`play()`をすぐに呼ぶ場合には、`prepareToPlay()`は不要です。)

Comment: ご丁寧にありがとうございます！